# ldap authentication login only works with typing in the hashed password

Tags: node.js, authentication, ldap, ldap-client, ssha

I have a nodejs application with angular frontend. When I want to login with a user it only works when I type in the ssha hashed password. But with the plain text password I can't login.

the ldap client configuration ist:

```
function auth(user, password, successFn){
  var opts ={
    scope: 'sub',
    filter: '(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=' + user + '))',
  };

  var callback = function (err, res){
    handleResult(collect, err, res);
  };

  var collect = {
    list: [],
    entry: function(entry){ this.list.push(entry); },
    done: function(){
      var correct = this.list.length == 1;
      if ( correct ){
        var pw = this.list[0].userPassword;
        correct = (pw == password);
      }
      if ( correct ){
        var role = this.list[0].employeeType;
        successFn(role[0]);
      }
      else{
        successFn(correct);
      }

    }
  }
```

and

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  var user = req.body.username;
  var pw = req.body.password;

  ldap.auth(user, pw, function(role){  
    if ( role ){
      req.session.user = user;
      req.session.userRole = role;
```

Is there something wrong with the code in nodejs or is this a configuration mistake o the ldap server? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a major security concern.
Your code is not using LDAP Authentication (i.e. an LDAP Bind Request). It retrieves the user entry and compare the password field with the user input.
But most LDAP server will hash the user password to secure it.
I would strongly recommend to change the auth method to perform a Bind to validate the password and then collect the Roles.

Comment: this is just a part of my code. I hve got a ldpa.bind function. My problem is that the ldap can't login with the plain password tiped in the frontend. It can't compare it with the ssha hashed password in the root user.

Comment: LDAP servers do authentication by comparing a plaintext password input by the user against a hashed and secure version they keep in their database. If it fails for your user, it either mean the user DN is not correct (user cannot be found) or the passwords are different. While you cannot see why authentication fail on the client side (for security reasons), the server's log should give you a better indication of the failure to authenticate. Note that the root User is a special user and often not in the same location as the other users (meaning you may not find it using a subtree search).

Comment: The login works bot only when I type in the hashed password, it doesn't work with the plain text. Do you know why?

Comment: Could be a misconfiguration of your LDAP server, or most likely how the password was added to the server.

Comment: that was the problem I thought of, I configured the ldap server in eclipse with the apache server plugin for eclipse. Do you know what configuration I have to do get my problem solved?

Comment: You didn't even mentioned which ldap server you are using... But I would recommend to ask to the community that supports it.